# Write text into an inputbox using buttons

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function

i'm trying to create some kind of Desktop Keyboard (using/writing kyrillic letters in my text field). I came across the Problem that i can only write the first letter because of the assignment of the variable.

can someone tell me an easy way to get around that?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function rukeyboard() {
                var newtext = document.Keyboard.A.value; // <-- Problem is that newtext is only pointed to Keyboard.A but should be usable for 33 letters
                document.Keyboard.outputtext.value += newtext;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="Keyboard">
            <input type="button" name="A" value="A" onClick="rukeyboard();">
            <input type="button" name="B" value="B" onClick="rukeyboard();">
            <input name="outputtext">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
function rukeyboard(newtext) {
    document.Keyboard.outputtext.value += newtext;
}
```

```html
<form name="Keyboard">
    <input type="button" name="A" value="A" onClick="rukeyboard(this.value);">
    <input type="button" name="B" value="B" onClick="rukeyboard(this.value);">
    <input name="outputtext" value="">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your purpose :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function rukeyboard(button) {
                var newtext = button.value; // <-- Problem is that newtext is only pointed to Keyboard.A but should be usable for 33 letters
                document.Keyboard.outputtext.value += newtext;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="Keyboard">
            <input type="button" name="A" value="A" onClick="rukeyboard(this);">        <input type="button" name="B" value="B" onClick="rukeyboard(this);">
            <input name="outputtext">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/wet32n06/

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this solution.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            function rukeyboard() {
              //  var newtext = document.Keyboard.A.value; // <-- Problem is that newtext is only pointed to Keyboard.A but should be usable for 33 letters
                document.Keyboard.outputtext.value += document.activeElement.value;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="Keyboard">
            <input type="button" name="A" value="A" onClick="rukeyboard();">
            <input type="button" name="B" value="B" onClick="rukeyboard();">
            <input name="outputtext">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

But personally I will prefer using jquery to associate the functions, as there are lots of input tag and u have to manually call for each input tag. 
So One good way will be using [jquery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to loop through all inputs, and bind the function using [jquery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to the inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using Jquery

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <button value="A" name="A">A</button>
    <button value="B" name="B">B</button>
    <input id="outputtext" name="outputtext">
</body>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
     $(document).on("click", "button", function() {
          $("#outputtext").val($("#outputtext").val() + "" + this.value);
     });
</script>
```